# how do I validate an input to accept only a single word in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

How do I validate an input to accept only a single word and not multiple words inside Laravel's validation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom validation rule for this, here I register a new rule on a service provider using `extend` method of `Validator` facade:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('single_word', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return is_string($value) && ! preg_match('/\s/u', $value);
        });
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```php
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|single_word',
]);
```

You can check other ways to register a custom validation rules here on the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules